# Remove a Student ID from an ArrayList, and display all the courses added into the arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

Below is a case that should remove the student ID, running in main testClass. However is not removing anything from the arrayList. I think 'findIdNum' should be used somehow in the 'else' statement part of the code, but i don't know how to.

Main question: How to remove the ID from arrayList so that when i go to admissions and view all students, the one that was removed should not pop up in display.

```
   case 1: //Drop the student (BUG101: NOTHING HAPPENS)

            String findIdNum = GetData.getString("Enter Student ID that needs to be dropped.");
            db.search(findIdNum);
            if(!db.inList())
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The ID: " + findIdNum + " is not in the databse.");       
            else
            {                  
                 int index = db.getIndex();                                                                                       
                 db.add(db.remove(index));
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Student" + findIdNum + " removed from the system.");                                         
            }     

   break;
```

Another bug in main testClass was that only the first name of the course that was from a userInput would come to display, rather than all of the courses.

Main question: How can i have all the courses display from the arrayList after userInput types in (i.e MAT200, then MAT3000) both MAT2000 and MAT3000 should display rather than MAT2000 alone.

```
case 2:                         

      ArrayList getList = db.getList();                                                                                                              
      ArrayList getCourseList = db.getCourseList(); 

      if(getCourseList.isEmpty())                                                                                                 
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No courses in the cart.");                                                                                                
      else                                                                                            
         {                                                                                                        
         String x = "";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
         int length = db.getSize();                                                                                                       
         try                                                                                              
            {                                                                                                  
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) 

            {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
             StudentCourse    sq = (StudentCourse)getCourseList.get(i);                                                                                                                    
             StudentAccounts q = (StudentAccounts)getList.get(i);  

             x += "Student ID:\t"  + q.getStudent().getId()+                                                                                                          
                  "\nName:\t"      + q.getStudent().getName().getFirst()+ " 
                                   "+q.getStudent().getName().getLast() +                                                                                                                                
                  "\nDate:\t"        + df.format(now)+                                                                                                         
                  "\nCourses:\t"   + sq.getCourse() + "\n";   

            }                                                                                                   
            display(x, "All Students" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                                                                                                   
            }                                                                                                      
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){}                                                                                               
       }                                                                                                         
   break;
```

Below is the DataBase Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DataBase 
{
        ArrayList <StudentAccounts> list;
        ArrayList <StudentCourse> courseList;

        StudentAccounts sa ;
        StudentCourse sc;
        int index;
        boolean found = false;

        DataBase()
        {
                list = new ArrayList<StudentAccounts> ();                                                       //Inserts a new Student acount into the ArrayList
                courseList = new ArrayList <StudentCourse> ();
        }

        ArrayList getList()                 {return list;}
        ArrayList getCourseList()           {return courseList; } 

        StudentCourse getCourses()          {return sc;}    
        StudentCourse removeCourse(int d)   {return courseList.remove(d); }
        StudentAccounts getStudent()        {return sa;}
        StudentAccounts remove(int d)       {return list.remove(d); }  

        boolean inList()                    {return found;}                                                                                  //Looks in the ArrayList  
        boolean isEmpty()                   {return list.isEmpty();}  
        int getIndex()                      {return list.indexOf(sa);}      
        int getSize()                       {return list.size();}                                                                             // return the amount of strings in the Array     
        int getCourseSize()                 {return courseList.size(); }

        void add(StudentAccounts s)         {list.add(s);}         
        void add(StudentCourse sc)          {courseList.add(sc);}


         void search(String key){
                  found = false;
                  int i = 0;      
                  while (!found && i < getSize() )
                  { 
                             StudentAccounts sl = list.get(i);
                             if(sl.getStudent().getId().equalsIgnoreCase(key))
                             {                    
                                 sa = sl;
                                 found = true;      
                                 index = i;
                             }
                             else{}
                 i++;
                 }
         }        
}
```

Below is class Student

```
package student;

//This class does 1 task, obtains student information.

public class Student
{                       
        private Name name;
        private String idNUM;
        StudentCourse course;

        public Student(Name n, String  idNum)
        {
                    this.name    = n;
                    this.idNUM = idNum;              
        }

        public void changeIdNumber(String id)
        {
                    idNUM = id;
        }

        public Name getName()                     {return name; }
        public String getId()                     {return idNUM; }            
}
```

Below is StudentAccounts class

```
    public class StudentAccounts 
    {         
        public Student stud; 

        public StudentAccounts (Student s) {this.stud = s; }           
        public Student getStudent()        {return stud; }
    }
```

Below is the class StudentCourse

```
public class StudentCourse
{
        public String sc;

        public StudentCourse(String s) {sc = s;}   
        public String getCourse()      {return sc; }       
}
```

Comment: Can you expand the 2nd question, it's not clear what is supposed to be happening or what is happening.

Comment: After creating the student account and provided with a random ID, 
I log in, and start choosing classes, Lets say i am taking 2 classes, i type in MAT1 and MAT2, then when i click "view status" it displays student name, ID, and (instead of it displaying the 2 classes MAT1 and MAT2) it only displays the first class entered, MAT1.

Answer (score 2):

What is this line meant to do?  `db.add(db.remove(index));`

You are removing it and then re-adding it, so that's why it isn't removed.

Q2:

What are you iterating through here

```
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
```

Students?

But then you do

```
StudentCourse    sq = (StudentCourse)getCourseList.get(i);
```

So if `i` is the student index, does the line above make sense?